# How to get the current HttpServletResponse in JBoss 4.2.3.GA login module

Tags: java, jboss, jboss-4.2.x

How can I get the current HttpServletResponse in JBoss 4.2.3.GA login module?

For HttpServletRequest I can do:

```
PolicyContext.getContext("javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest");
```

Have tried changing the string but no luck, an exception is thrown.

Is there any way to get the current HttpServletResponse in JBoss 4.2.3.GA login module?

Comment: try with InitialContext maybe ? the application context is Servlet context so the path will be "/" ...

Answer (score 0):

I probably don't understand the question at all, but when you want to affect a request or response that some other Servlet is going to handle, isn't that the function of ServletFilters?  A ServletFilter put on the servlet handling the login has access to both the ServletRequest and the ServletResponse.